# MySQL : update with Where clause in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

I used to know how to do this but a lack of practice made me lose it.

I am trying to update usernames from a table by comparing matching email in another.
basically the first table has username empty, while the other has username and emails filled.
here is my wrong query :

```
UPDATE users SET username = (SELECT Username FROM clients WHERE email in mail)
```

email is from my clients table, mail is from my users table

Comment: Well unless you want to update _all_ records with _one_ value, you will want a WHERE clause in the outer query as well …

Comment: you need to check how to use join table in update

Comment: can you provide structure of both table ?

Comment: I do want to update all, the first table has empty values for usernames, while the other has usernames in, both have an email column, email and mail

Comment: _“I do want to update all”_ – yes, but not all with the _same_ value, which of course happens when you do an UPDATE without a limiting WHERE clause.

Comment: I have given you an exmple answer for your problem, only thing is we dont know the connection between users and clients to make it 100% correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest update with using JOIN with UPDATE, something like this should work

```
UPDATE users 
    INNER JOIN
    #your relationship / for example
    clients ON (users.id = clients.user_id) 
SET 
    users.username = clients.email
WHERE
    users.username IS NULL
```

Just make sure ON clause is correct relation that you have between users and clients and it should update all records in users username column with email from clients

Comment: here is mail and email is same see in comment

Comment: mail, email in which tables ? if they are they same what you can do is : clients ON (users.email = client.mail )

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information to get a clear answer.

If you don't set a WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement, you will update all records with the same value, which is probably not what you want

If you want to update the *users* table with some info on **matching** records in the *client* table, then you need to join both tables on your matching field. Something like this :

```
UPDATE users U, clients C
SET u.username = c.username
WHERE U.email=C.email
AND C.email IN (...)
```

In this example I assumed that the email address was the matching field between the 2 tables (you should adapt this), and that you provide a list of target email addresses (you can remove this)